# Shared Preferences and Editor(Android) Relationship in Real Example

Tags: java, android, session, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I was able to compile projects from the internet that is related to Shared Preferences, but I can't understand the codes, even trying to read the documentation. Can you give real life examples examples where SharedPreferences and Editor is seen? or Can you sight any scenario that SharedPreferences's relationship with Editor and related codes that could implement SharedPreferences. I want to understand the basics. Thanks.

```
            // Shared Preferences
            SharedPreferences pref;

            // Editor for Shared preferences
            Editor editor;

            public SessionManager(Context context){
                this._context = context;
                pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
                editor = pref.edit();
            }

                /**
         * Create login session
         * */
        public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
            // Storing login value as TRUE
            editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

            // Storing name in pref
            editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

            // Storing email in pref
            editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

            // commit changes
            editor.commit();
        }   
/**
         * Check login method wil check user login status
         * If false it will redirect user to login page
         * Else won't do anything
         * */
        public void checkLogin(){
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
                // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                _context.startActivity(i);
            }

        }



        /**
         * Get stored session data
         * */
        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // user name
            user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

            // user email id
            user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

            // return user
            return user;
        }

        /**
         * Clear session details
         * */
        public void logoutUser(){
            // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

        /**
         * Quick check for login
         * **/
        // Get Login State
        public boolean isLoggedIn(){
            return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
        }
```

Comment: editor.putXXXXX(<KEY>, <VAKLUE>);editor.commit();

Comment: any basic concept that you can share?

Answer (score -1):

From the [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) itself

```
The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).
```

This is basically an xml that lies you data/data/"package name"/shared_prefs

Currently it does not supports multiprocess editing/accessing but will server your purpose.

You can use it to store user preferences like background color,text color, notification tone etc

Comment: in case you are downvoting any answer please let the person know the reason for it.